# Two WampServer installed on Windows 7

Tags: wampserver

Two WampServer installed on Windows 7, one on the c drive, another drive d I start WampServer d, localhost access is the c drive info, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 installes of the same WAMPServer on the same PC. And there is no reason to have 2 anyway.

You can have a 32 and a 64 bit WAMPServer installed on the same PC but again there is no reason to do that either

This is because the second install will uninstall the Apache and MySQL services created by the first install, and replace them with the Apache and MySQL from the second install.

Comment: thanks for you kindly help me. I installed two wamp on my server that just a tset. And now, I got it.